# Autowired instance's property is null even after setting value

Tags: java, autowired

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/myProject")
public class myClassController {

    @Autowired
    Mydata data;
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/mydetails/{id}")
    public @ResponseBody Mydata mymethod(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id,
                                         HttpServletRequest request) {
        data.setId(id);
        return data;
    }
}
@Component
class Mydata {
    private String Id;

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(String s) {
        this.Id= Id;
    }
}
```

**Question**
Here I am autowiring 'Mydata', and in mymethod(), I am able to see the id having some value during debugging.
After setting the value, it is becoming null.
ie) data.getId() is returning null.
pls note: 'data' is not null.
When I am instantiating Mydata using new, its working fine.
What is the issue with my autowiring? please help..

Comment: Independent of this problem you should rethink your approach. What you have here might not be tread safe.

Answer (score 2):

It is not an error related to Spring and autowiring.
It is just a simple assignment error.

Here you don't assign the parameter to the field :

```
public void setId(String s) {
    this.Id= Id;
}
```

You assign the field to itself. It has no effect.

You should rather do it :

```
public void setId(String s) {
     this.Id= s;
}
```

And as a side note, if you want to respect naming convention : variable names should start with a lower case (`id` instead of `Id`).

Comment: oops! that was a typo.. @davidxxx

Comment: These are things that happen. Generally, I endeavor to  regenerate getters and setters with IDE rather than writing or modifying it manually. These are so simple methods as we underestimate manual errors.

Comment: That was a typo, that got in while I was posting here.. I did it right in my code. Can you find any issue in my autowiring? @davidxxx

Comment: ah okay. In this case, you should edit your question in this case with the **exact actual code**.